# On the definition of probability function of discrete r.v. in DeGroot & Schervish "Probability and Statistics" (relation to probability mass function)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am reading DeGroot & Schervish’s text “Probability and Statistics”, and when it gets to defining the *probability function* of a discrete random variable $X$, they write:

> The *probability function* (p.f.) of a r.v. $X$ is defined as the function $f$ such that, for every real number $x$, 
>   $$ f(x) := P(X=x).$$

To me this does not look completely ok, because – in some sense – this function $f$ is continuous (actually it is continuous a.e.): indeed, it is essentially $f = 0$ a.e., and that would make the definition not really different from that of a C.D.F..

Let me explain this point a bit more in detail. What I mean is that usually the CDF is taken as more general because the CDF itself is an a.e. continuous function that can address probability distributions without caring if the underlying random variable is *continuous* or *discrete*. But, given what is written in the book, there wouldn't be such a big difference conceptually between the definition of p.f. that can be found there, and the definition of a CDF, at least when it comes to **continuity**.

Thus, here my **questions**:

- am I right concerning this ambiguity?
- Should we rather proceed by selecting a subset $S$ of the reals where the r.v. $X$ maps the elements of the state space $\Omega$, and then using this $S$ as the domain of the p.f.?
  *[This is how a probability mass function is usually defined, right?]*

I am looking forward to your feedbacks.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Ok, the pdf is not defined as a function such that $f(x)=P(X=x)$ but as a function $f$ such that $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)dt$. So, I think the two definitions are different.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Actually, what I meant is that usually the CDF is taken as more general because it can address probability distributions with a a.e. continuous function (the CDF) without caring if there is a pdf or only a pf. In that case, there wouldn't be such a big difference *conceptually* between this definition, and a definition of a CDF, at least when it comes the the **continuity**.

Comment: I will incorporate this point in my question, to make it more explicit.

Comment: For first courses, an approach that primarily deals with discrete and with absolutely continuous distributions, and treats them somewhat separately, is traditional.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I edited the question. Actually my point is not that is should not be done (IMO that book is amazing from a pedagogical point of view). My point is that the definition is not really sound, because they define a p.f. $f$ as a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_+$, and – as a side effect – defined in this way, $f$ is a.e. continuous.

Comment: The definition holds for **discrete** random variables (and is then perfectly sound). Thus, considerations about the function $f$ being zero almost everywhere are correct and offtopic since the formula to deduce the CDF of a discrete random variable $X$ from its PMF $f$ is $$P(X\leqslant x)=\sum_{t\leqslant x}f(t).$$ This should not be confused with $f$ being the PDF of some continuous random variable $X$, in which case $$P(X\leqslant x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)dt.$$

Comment: @Did Thanks for the feedback. I see the point, and actually after having written the comment I thought that "sound" was really a misuse on my part. Anyway, I was simply wondering about the fact that defined in that way, the p.f. and the CDF are both continuous.

Comment: Neither the PMF nor the CDF of a discrete random variable are continuous, actually (that is, for the usual topology...).